# Refresh a single database field in a div on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to refresh a single DIV on my page called #total_number. Inside that DIV is a column of a table i've called into the DIV. The DIV counts the number number of records submitted.

What I want it to do is when I submit - I want the DIV to count the total number of records submitted.

```
<div id="total_number"></div>

<form id="form1" name="form4" method="POST" action="pay.asp">
    <label for="comment2"></label>
    <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="60" />
    <input name="comme" type="hidden" id="comme" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="comfn" type="hidden" id="comfn" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" fname ").Value)%>&nbsp;<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item("lname ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="item" type="hidden" id="item" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" item ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="ctype" type="hidden" id="ctype" value="album" />
    <input name="price" type="hidden" id="price" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
    <input name="imageField" type="image" id="changePanel" src="imgs/buttons/Untitled-1.png" align="top" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.asp",
                data: data
            }).success(function() {

                $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Photo has been added to your favorites!</div>");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".messages").fadeOut(function() {
                        $(".messages").remove();
                    });
                }, 1000);
                $("input[type=text]").val("");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want a code that will only refresh the DIV #total_number on click on the submit button.

Comment: I can't see ` #total_number` in ur code!

Comment: sorry i didn't included that, but its now included. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like the following:

```
<div id="total_number" count="0" readonly>No submitted records yet!</div>

<form id="form1" name="form4" method="POST" action="pay.asp">
    <label for="comment2"></label>
    <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="60" />
    <input name="comme" type="hidden" id="comme" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="comfn" type="hidden" id="comfn" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" fname ").Value)%>&nbsp;<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item("lname ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="item" type="hidden" id="item" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" item ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="ctype" type="hidden" id="ctype" value="album" />
    <input name="price" type="hidden" id="price" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
    <input name="imageField" type="image" id="changePanel" src="imgs/buttons/Untitled-1.png" align="top" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.asp",
                data: data
            }).success(function() {
                var count = parseInt($("$total_number").attr('count'));
                var nCount = (count+1);
                $("$total_number").attr('count',nCount).html(nCount+' Records been submitted');
                $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Photo has been added to your favorites!</div>");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".messages").fadeOut(function() {
                        $(".messages").remove();
                    });
                }, 1000);
                $("input[type=text]").val("");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. just like facebook, when you comment on a photo is counts the total without refreshing

Comment: i dont kow how to refresh that div onsubmit of the form.

Comment: it's in my answer, the code will refresh the div based on previous value and adding +1 each time submit process success!

Comment: i'm not able to submit. when i click on the submit button nothing happens and the variables still remains in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try Something

```
<div id="total_number"></div>   

<form id="form1" name="form4" method="POST" action="pay.asp">
    <label for="comment2"></label>
    <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="60" />
    <input name="comme" type="hidden" id="comme" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="comfn" type="hidden" id="comfn" value="<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item(" fname ").Value)%>&nbsp;<%=(rs_user.Fields.Item("lname ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="item" type="hidden" id="item" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" item ").Value)%>" />
    <input name="ctype" type="hidden" id="ctype" value="album" />
    <input name="price" type="hidden" id="price" value="<%=(rs_resq.Fields.Item(" email ").Value)%>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
    <input name="imageField" type="image" id="changePanel" src="imgs/buttons/Untitled-1.png" align="top" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.asp",
                data: data
            }).success(function() {
                var count = parseInt($("$total_number").attr('count'));
                var nCount = (count+1);

               $("#total_number").html(nCount); //Puts response data inside <div id="total_number"></div>

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

OR

```
<div id="submit">ajax</div> 
<div id="div_element"></div> 
<script> 
$('#submit').click(function(event){ 
   $("#div_element").load('URL?html=some_arguments');  

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: it does the submission but can't count unless you press f5 to refresh the whole page

Comment: take it in iframe then

Comment: plz can you show me how cos i'm new to the jquery stuff